# Spring boot application startup freezing during config bootstrapping

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

My spring boot application is hanging during startup while bootstrapping configurations from a local config server. I've tried enabling debug logs but have not found anything meaningful.

This is where the application startup hangs

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.2)

2022-01-09 09:22:33.462  INFO 77647 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2022-01-09 09:22:33.629  INFO 77647 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=alfred-app, profiles=[default], label=null, version=null, state=null
2022-01-09 09:22:33.630  INFO 77647 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configClient'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-file:launcher/alfred-app.yml'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-class path resource [launcher/application.yml'}]
```

**Versions**

```
    <spring-boot.version>2.4.2</spring-boot.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
 <pivotal.spring.cloud.services.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</pivotal.spring.cloud.services.version>
```

My config server (also running on Spring Boot 2.4.2):

```
2022-01-09 10:03:52.756  INFO 77050 --- [nio-8888-exec-5] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: Config resource 'file [launcher/alfred-app.yml]' via location 'file:./launcher/'
2022-01-09 10:03:52.756  INFO 77050 --- [nio-8888-exec-5] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: Config resource 'class path resource [launcher/application.yml]' via location 'classpath:/launcher/'
```

Has anyone run into this before? I'm not sure what other troubleshooting options I have.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing required configuration values for my application, but for some reason spring wasn't failing the validations and stopping the app. When I copied my the yaml files from the config server into my project locally, Spring started to report the failed validation on the missing properties. Not sure why it wouldn't do that when pulling the configurations from the config server, but this issue is now resolved.